# How to convert string to long long in c

Tags: c

How to convert string to long long

```
int main() {
  char **ptr;
  long long val1 = strtoumax("1234567890123456",ptr, 10);
  printf("%ull\n",val1);
}
```

Its prints only 1015724736ll. How can I make it to print 1234567890123456

Answer (score 4):

Use [strtoll](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtoll) , strtoumax is for converting to a uintmax_t, which is usually not a long long.

Note that your printf format specifier is wrong too, there's no such thing as "%ull".
"%ull" will get interpreted as the format specfier "%u" and an ordinary string of "ll". Passing an long long to be formatted as an unsigned int("%u") will likely give you unpredictable results.

You need to use

```
 printf("%lld\n", val1);
```

If you had an unsigned long long, you'd use "%llu"

Comment: That's true but not OP's problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. use `unsigned long long` instead of `long long`
2. use `strtoull` instead of `strtoumax`
3. use `printf("%llu\n",val1);`

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues.

Instead of `printf("%ull\n",val1);` use `printf("%llu\n",val1);`.  Put "ll" first.

`ptr` should be `char *ptr` and then `foo(..., &ptr, 10)`.  (this prevents *bad* things as this parameters needs to point to memory you own.)

`long long val1` should be `unsigned long long val1` - you appear to want to use unsigned integers in the rest of the code

`strtoumax` should be `strtoull` - to match your destination type of `unsigned long long`.

Comment: what should I have to use strtoumax or strtoll

Comment: `strtoumax` strives for correct answers for the type `uintmax_t`.  `strtoll` does so for type `long long`.  You appear to want to user type `unsigned long long`, thus recommend `strtoull`.

Comment: @chrylis I s/b avoiding "s/b" and should be using "should be".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strtoll`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoll/).

And for the format specifier in `printf`, use `%ll`, `u` stands for unsigned, which `val1` isn't.

If `unsigned long long` is what you want, declare `val1` as so, and use [`strtoull`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoull/) accordingly.